# Tracking all touches in for a designated UIViewController subclass

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitouch, uicollectionview, touchesbegan

I want to track all user touches within a designated UIViewController subclass, e.g. MyViewController.

As this UIViewController may contain UIKit-Elements, such as UIButtons, etc. I thought of lying a clear touch tracking UIView above the other views in MyViewController's view.

Now I get touch events sent to the UIView, but I don't know how to delegate the touches to the other subviews.

I already tried iterating over all MyViewController's view subviews (except the touch tracking UIView) and sending them touchesBegan:withEvent:, touchesMoved:withEvent:, etc.

But this does not work for UICollectionViews.

What I basically need is tracking all touch events in MyViewController's view frame.
MyViewController itself could inherit various other views that need to respond to touch events.

I also found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423174/detecting-all-touches-in-an-app) the idea to subclass UIWindow and to override sendEvent:
This would be possible in my case, but then I would have to enable/disable touch tracking whether MyViewController is visible or not.
Also I don't know yet how to differentiate between touchesBegan:withEvent, touchesMoved:withEvent:, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
tubtub

in MyViewController.m

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    VETouchTrackingView *touchTrackingView;
    touchTrackingView = [[VETouchTrackingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    touchTrackingView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    self.touchTrackingView = touchTrackingView;
    [self.view addSubview:self.touchTrackingView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.touchTrackingView];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the touch tracking I need by overriding sendEvent: in my UIWindow subclass.

This works pretty nice.

Here is the github project for anyone who also needs this: https://github.com/bhr/BHTouchTracking